# Replace a string but only the second occurence of that string

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have some text in a file.

I'm using `Get-Content` to read a file, then using Regex `-replace` to find a pattern and replaced the contents.  This works perfect, until I come into a situation where I need to just replace the second occurrence of that string, and not the first or any after (in this case it only shows up twice anyway).

I want to search for "some string to find", and then replace only the second occurrence of this string.  I have searched trying to find examples of how to do this, but have come up short.  I can find how to replace portions of the string, but not entire separate occurrences of the full string.

Here is what works to replace all occurrences of a string.

```
(gc file.txt) -replace "Some string to find", "some string changed") | sc file.txt
```

Comment: Try `(gc file.txt) -replace "(str1.*?)str1", "${1}replaced" | sc file.txt`. To match whole words only, use `"\b(str1\b.*?)\bstr1\b"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$find="world"
$replace="nice"
$string="the world is world, no?"
$pos=$string.IndexOf($find, $string.IndexOf($find)+1)

if ($pos -ne -1)
{
    "{0}{1}{2}" -f $string.Substring(0, $pos), $replace, $string.Substring($pos + $find.Length) 
}
else
{
   $string 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Esperento.  I haven't had time to test this out yet, but I will try to do this today.

Can you explain the {0}{1}{2}, is this referencing an array position?  Thanks.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work when trying to read a file, and change the contents.

I can use your example and that works, but when I changed $string = gc file.txt, I then get an error when trying to run the next $pos= command.

Cannot find an overload for "IndexOf" and the argument count: "2".

Could this be because Get-Content loads each line as its own string?  Thanks.

Sorry

Comment: what is your PowerShell version?

Comment: 4.0 from Server 2012 R2

I think if we can make it work where 
    $string = "The world","is World","no?"
That will solve my problem.  Because each string is now saved on a separate "line" in the variable.

Lets say my file contains
*Red
*Blue
*Red
*Green

Now I want to find the second "Red" and replace it with something, but leave the first "Red" in place.  I know how to do this if everything was in a single string, but in this case it is not, they are separate lines.  I hope that gives a little more clarity on the problem?

Comment: I got this to work with your example Esperento57. :)

So the key is that Get-Content in PowerShell loads each new line as a separate string.  So starting with PS 3.0 we can now use Get-Content "Path to text file" - Raw.  That will make it into a single string.

Then using your example above I was able to make this work.

However, would it be possible to explain "{0}{1}{2}" -f $string.Substring(0, $pos), $replace, $string.Substring($pos + $find.Length)?

I don't understand why this works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if its not variable and its always just the first occurrence to jump over, you could simply do something like

```
mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf("string to match")).replace("string to match", "some string changed")
```

(js example)

Comment: Thank you FluffyNights.

Using mystring.substring though, how do I use that with get-content (gc)?  I want PowerShell to read content, and chance it and save it back.

Would I use:

    (gc file.txt) | mystring.substring....?

Thank you.

Comment: im not familiar with powershell, but from what i know, methods are almost the same, so you would probably use mystring.Substring(mystring.indexOf(...)).Replace(...). if you dont get it running, checkout https://4sysops.com/archives/strings-in-powershell-replace-compare-concatenate-split-substring/

Answer (score 0):

If you want replace second word of text try replace like this (word to find use ponctuation) :

```
$find="world", "world.", "world;", "world," , "world?", "world!", "world:"
$replace="nice"
$string="the world is world, no?"
$array=$string -split " "
$Nbfounded=0
$result=""


foreach ($item in $array)
{
    $Founded=$false

    if ($item -in $find)
    {
       $Nbfounded++
       $Founded=$true 
    }


    if ($Founded -and $Nbfounded -eq 2)
    {
        $result=$result + ' ' + $replace
    }
    else
    {
        $result=$result + ' ' + $item
    }

}

$result.TrimStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself recently, and I wanted to derive something robust enough to specify any occurrence of a substring within a string.  I found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940438/639580) by [Esperento57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735690/esperento57) that I adapted into the following function which will change the *n<sup>th</sup>* occurrence as passed to the parameter:

```
Function Set-Replacement {
   Param( $string, $find, $replace, $occurrence )
   If ( ($occurrence -gt 0) -and ($occurrence -lt ($split=$string -split $find).Count) ) {
         ($split[0..($occurrence-1)] -join $find) + $replace + ($split[($occurrence)..$split.Count] -join $find)
   } Else {
      $string
   }
}
```

Here are some examples.

- Change 1<sup>st</sup> occurrence of *dog* to *poodle*.

  ```
    PS C:\> Set-Replacement "The dog bit another dog." "dog" "poodle" 1
    The poodle bit another dog.
  ```
- Change 2<sup>nd</sup> occurrence of *dog* to *mailman*.

  ```
    PS C:\> Set-Replacement "The dog bit another dog." "dog" "mailman" 2
    The dog bit another mailman.
  ```

Substrings that are not found or occurrences that are not valid will leave the original input string intact.

```
PS C:\> Set-Replacement "The dog bit another dog." "dog" "mailman" 0
The dog bit another dog.

PS C:\> Set-Replacement "The dog bit another dog." "dog" "mailman" 3
The dog bit another dog.

PS C:\> Set-Replacement "The dog bit another dog." "cat" "mailman" 1
The dog bit another dog.
```