# How to replace nth character occurence with another character

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

Given this string:

```
2017.12.21.5
```

...how would one convert it to this:

```
2017.12.21-5
```

The match will always be on the 3rd occurrence of `.`.

I'm running this in a PowerShell script.

I've tried too many permutations to list here; so far I haven't even come close.

**--EDIT--**

In addition, the second and third octets (the month and day) will vary between one and two digits. The fourth (the release for that day) may also contain three digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to target and replace the nth occurrence of a character, so we just have to target the whole string and copy over the unchanged parts

```
"2017.12.21.5" -replace '(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\.(\d*)', '$1-$2'
2017.12.21-5
```

Comment: That works, thank you. But I neglected to provide necessary detail in my question: the number of digits in the second and third octets is not always 2. Is there a way to account for this variance?

Comment: "2017.12.21.5" -replace '(\d{4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})\.(\d*)', '$1-$2'

Comment: Got it. And the * after the last \d will match any number of digits, correct?

Comment: That is correct. You can replace that with a constraint value if it will always be a certain length. I just put that so it will have some flexibility.

Comment: Thanks. This regex business completely baffles me. I'm impressed that you have such a good handle on it.

Comment: I work with regex a LOT on the Linux command line. I have actually never touched Powershell. ;-) I had to find an interpreter online to make sure things would work as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161785/discussion-between-intexx-and-sorak).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to match 3rd occurrence of .

```
(?<=\.\d+\.\d+)\.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use split and join

```
$var='2017.12.21.5'
$split=$var -split '\.'
($split[0..2] -join '.') + '-' + $split[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I simplified the last Function to this.

```
$InputStr = "2017.12.21.5"
$matchVal = '.'
$replaceVal='-'
$num = 3

#searched is:
$OutputStr=$InputStr

$positions = (0..($InputStr.ToCharArray().Count-2)|ForEach-Object{$InputStr.IndexOf($matchVal,$_)}|Select-Object -Unique)
if($num -lt $positions.Count+1){
    $OutputStr = $InputStr.Remove($positions[$num-1],1).Insert($positions[$num-1], $replaceVal)
}
```

so it gets all positions of the `$matchVal` in `$positions`and then checks if `$num` <= Count of positions. If so, the `$InputStr`'s char at `$position[$num-1]` will be replaced with the `$replaceVal`.